# How to get, compare and set a registry key value in hex

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I want to get the the `state` key value from below address in hex

```
RegistryKey winTrust = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
  @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing", true);
```

Then compare it with `23c00` value, and if it's not the same, set it to `23c00`

```
string currentKey = winTrust.GetValue("State").ToString();
if (!currentKey.Equals("23c00"))
 {
   winTrust.SetValue("State", "23c00", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
   winTrust.Close();
 }
```

It's not working as it gets and compare the decimal value.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution.

```
// Convert value as a hex in a string variable
string currentKey = Convert.ToInt32(winTrust.GetValue("State").ToString()).ToString("x");
if (!currentKey.Equals("23c00"))
 {
  winTrust.SetValue("State", 0x00023c00, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
  winTrust.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get and set the value as an integer.

```
int value = Int32.Parse(winTrust.GetValue("State"));
if (value != 0x23c00)
   winTrust.SetValue("State", 0x23c00, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
winTrust.Close();
```